# Python - Inaccuracy while computing arcsin

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, trigonometry

I'm trying to implement arcsin in Python without using any external library.

Here's my code:

```
from time import process_time as pt

class TrigoCalc(metaclass=__readonly):
    # This class evaluates various Trigonometric functions 
    # including Inverse Trigonometric functions
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        raise Exception("Value can't be changed")
    

    @staticmethod
    def asin(x):
        '''Implementation from Taylor series
        asin(x) => summation[(2k)! * x^(2k + 1) / (2^(2k) * (k!)^2 * (2k + 1))]
                  k = [0, inf)
        x should be real
        '''
        # a0 = 1                                                                           
        # a1 = 1/(2*3)                                                                     
        # a2 = 1/2 * 3/(4*5) 
        # a3 = 1/2 * 3/4 * 5/(6*7)
        # a4 = 1/2 * 3/4 * 5/6 * 7/(8*9)
        # a5 = 1/2 * 3/4 * 5/6 * 7/8 * 9/(10*11)
        # a6 = 1/2 * 3/4 * 5/6 * 7/8 * 9/10 * 11/(12*13)
        # a7 = 1/2 * 3/4 * 5/6 * 7/8 * 9/10 * 11/12 * 13/(14*15)
        # a8 = 1/2 * 3/4 * 5/6 * 7/8 * 9/10 * 11/12 * 13/14 * 15/(16*17)
        # a9 = 1/2 * 3/4 * 5/6 * 7/8 * 9/10 * 11/12 * 13/14 * 15/16 * 17/(18*19)
        # a10 = 1/2 * 3/4 * 5/6 * 7/8 * 9/10 * 11/12 * 13/14 * 15/16 * 17/18 * 19/(20*21)
        
        # taking 10 coefficients for arriving at a common sequence
        
        # N = n, D = n + 1; (N/D) --> Multiplication, number of times the coefficient number, n >= 1
        
        start_time = pt()

        coeff_list = []
        NUM_ITER = 10000
        for k in range(NUM_ITER):
            if k == 0:
                coeff_list.append(1)
            else:
                N = 1
                D = N + 1
                C = N/D
                if k >= 2:
                    for i in range(k-1):
                        N += 2; D += 2
                        C = C * N/D
                coeff_list.append(C)
        
        __sum = 0
        for k in range(NUM_ITER):
            n = coeff_list[k] * math_utils.power(x, 2*k + 1) / (2*k + 1)
            __sum += n
    
        # Radian conversion to degrees
        __sum = __sum/TrigoCalc.pi * 180
        
        end_time = pt()

        print(f'Execution time: {end_time - start_time} seconds')

        return __sum
```

#### Results

When `NUM_ITER` is `60` (Infinite series iterated 60 times), there is significant inaccuracy in computation at the `x = 1` pole, whereas `x = 1/2` gives 14 point precision.

```
In [2]: TrigoCalc.asin(0.5)
Execution time: 0.0 seconds
Out[2]: 30.000000000000007

In [3]: TrigoCalc.asin(1)
Execution time: 0.0 seconds
Out[3]: 85.823908877692
```

Execution Time in both runs is unnoticeable.

When `NUM_ITER` is `10000`, then at `x = 1` pole, the result is more accurate than previous run, but at `x = 1/2`, precision is exactly same.

```
In [4]: TrigoCalc.asin(0.5)
Execution time: 19.109375 seconds
Out[4]: 30.000000000000007

In [5]: TrigoCalc.asin(1)
Execution time: 19.109375 seconds
Out[5]: 89.67674183336727
```

Execution time in these 2 runs is very high for this type of calculation.

#### Problem

How can I balance the code, so that it gives at least 1-point precision at `x = 1` pole in lesser `NUM_ITER`?

Please feel free to give suggestions or updations to the code.

**Python Ver:** *3.7.7*

**EDIT :** Changes to the code for precise results with the help of @Joni's answer

1. Enclosing the Infinite Series computation into another function inside `asin()`:

   ```
    def asin(x):     
        def __arcsin_calc(x):                                        
            # ....                                                 
            # Computations                                               
            # ....                                                             
            # Removing the radian to degree conversion from this function             
            return __sum
   ```
2. Adding the limits to `x` using the new function inside `asin()` to avoid slow convergence:

   ```
    if -1.0 <= x < -0.5:
        return -(TrigoCalc.pi/2 - __arcsin_calc(math_utils.power((1 - x*x), 0.5))) / TrigoCalc.pi * 180    # Radian to Degree conversion

    elif -0.5 <= x <= 0.5:
        return __arcsin_calc(x)/TrigoCalc.pi * 180

    elif 0.5 < x <= 1.0:          
        return (TrigoCalc.pi/2 - __arcsin_calc(math_utils.power((1 - x*x), 0.5))) / TrigoCalc.pi * 180

    else:      
        raise ValueError("x should be in range of [-1, 1]")
   ```
3. Results:

   ```
    In [2]: TrigoCalc.asin(0.99)
    Execution time: 0.0 seconds
    Out[2]: 81.89022502527023

    In [3]: math.asin(0.99)/TrigoCalc.pi*180
    Out[3]: 81.89038554400582

    In [4]: TrigoCalc.asin(1)
    Execution time: 0.0 seconds
    Out[4]: 90.0

    In [5]: math.asin(1)/TrigoCalc.pi*180
    Out[5]: 90.0
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with `arcsin(1)` is that `arcsin(x)` goes vertical at x=1 (derivative grows without bound). Polynomial approximations like the Taylor series can't keep up with it. You get a very slow convergence, and would need a huge number of terms to get a decent approximation. You need to change how you approach the problem.

For example, for small x, `y = sin(pi/2 - x)` is approximately `1 - x^2/2`, from which you can derive the approximation `asin(y) = pi/2 - sqrt(2 - 2*y)`. This approximation is good for values very close to 1 - you could use this directly.

If you work a little harder you can prove the *exact* identity

```
asin(x) = pi/2 - 2*asin( sqrt( (1-x)/2 ) )
```

Using this identity, you can compute `asin(x)` for x near 1 using your existing `asin` function that's good for x near 0.

For example: To compute `asin(0.99)` you would compute:

```
asin(0.99) = pi/2 - 2*asin( sqrt( (1-.99)/2 ) )
           = pi/2 - 2*asin( sqrt(.005) )
           = pi/2 - 2*asin(0.07071067811865475)
```

... and then you would use your existing algorithm to get a high quality approximation for `asin(0.07071067811865475)`.

This is the technique used in production quality math library implementations - see for example [OpenLibm](https://github.com/JuliaMath/openlibm/blob/master/src/e_asin.c) or [fdlibm](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/index.html).

Comment: Wonderful idea to get a very precise result, reducing the limit of x to half. I used the formula: `asin(x) = pi/2 - arcsin(sqrt(1-x^2))` to get rid of the slow convergence of taylor series at `x = 1` pole. Cross-checking the result with the `math` library, got 3-point precision at `asin(0.99)`. I'd like to share the code. BTW I'm accepting this answer as the most appropriate :)

Answer (score 1):

An extremely basic approximation will give that `sum from 0 to N` approximate `arcsin` at `1e(-N)` (talking in radians).
Here, you are giving a result in degrees, because there is roughly a ratio of `1e2` between degrees and radians, you will need to set `NUM_ITER = 1e(N+2)` to approximate arcsin at `1e(-N)`.

Thus, for your specific question, you need to test with `N = 1` (1 point approx), thus `NUM_ITER = 1e(1+2) = 1,000`. This is not precise at all but give an idea of the value you are looking for.

Then, if you want to look for the exact value, I do not see an exact mathematical method to use every time (for whatever x.point precision).
However, you can use a dichotomy algorithm to find `NUM_ITER`, if it is the goal of your algorithm. The first approximation will reduce your time of your calculation.

The precise approximation came from the ratio or `x^O(n)` and `4^O(n)`, `4^O(n)` is greater. We can approximate on term of the sum with `O(1/10^n)`.

If someone can perform a precise calculus I will be extremely happy to see it.